# What does the option "return_to" mean in erlang:trace/3?

Tags: erlang

In erlang doc:

> **return_to** Used in conjunction with the call trace flag. Trace the
>   actual return from a traced function back to its caller. Only works
>   for functions traced with the local option to erlang:trace_pattern/3.
>
> The semantics is that a trace message is sent when a call traced
>   function actually returns, that is, when a chain of tail recursive
>   calls is ended. There will be only one trace message sent per chain of
>   tail recursive calls, why the properties of tail recursiveness for
>   function calls are kept while tracing with this flag. Using call and
>   return_to trace together makes it possible to know exactly in which
>   function a process executes at any time.
>
> To get trace messages containing return values from functions, use the
>   {return_trace} match_spec action instead.
>
> Message tags: return_to.

What is "actual return"? I tested a tail recursive function, but it seems no difference.

Following is my test.erl:

```
-module(test).

-compile(export_all).

-record(state, {stacks=[]}).

test_tracer() ->
    Tracer = spawn_tracer(),
    erlang:trace_pattern({?MODULE, '_', '_'}, [], [local]),
    erlang:trace(self(), true, [call,
                                arity,
                                return_to,
                                %% procs,
                                %% running,
                                timestamp,
                                {tracer, Tracer}]),
    loop(100),
    Tracer!dump.

spawn_tracer() ->
    spawn(fun()-> trace_listener(#state{}) end).

trace_listener(State) ->
    receive
        dump ->
            io:format("~p", [lists:reverse(State#state.stacks)]);
        {trace_ts, Pid, call, MFA, Ts} ->
            Stacks = State#state.stacks,
            trace_listener(State#state{stacks=[MFA|Stacks]});
        _Term ->
            io:format("~p~n", [_Term]),
            trace_listener(State)
    end.

loop(0) -> ok;
loop(N) -> loop(N-1).
```

Whether there is `return_to` or not, it prints 101 `{test,loop,1}`.

I supposed that it should only return one `{test,loop,1}` with `return_to`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the return_to flag doesn't disable the tail calls, it merely traces where/who the final result is returned to.

Change the code to fit to the screen:

```
...
loop(10),
timer:sleep(100),
Tracer ! dump.
```

With return_to enabled you will get the message:

```
{trace_ts,<0.348.0>,return_to,{test,test_tracer,0},{1405,153820,908198}}
```

It means the loop/1 function returned its result to test:test_tracer/0.

There's not such a message without return_to.

To get the return values you need to change the pattern:

```
erlang:trace_pattern({?MODULE, '_', '_'}, [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}], [local]),
```

Now you will get the messages like:

```
{trace_ts,<0.657.0>,return_from,{test,loop,1},ok,{1405,155132,517284}}
```

Comment: Sorry, but may I know why add timer:sleep/1?

Comment: Just to make sure all trace messages are processed when `dump' is received. It's probably not needed for loop(10).